# WriteXml recursive call throws exception regarding StartAttribute c#

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, xml-serialization

```
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter w)
    {
        w.WriteAttributeString("Name", Name);

        w.WriteAttributeString("Type", GetType().Name);

        w.WriteStartElement("Actions");

        foreach (object obj in Actions)
        {
            if (obj is IAction)
            {
                XmlSerializer itemxml = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

                itemxml.Serialize(w, obj);
            }
            else if (obj is ActionGroup)
            {
                var group = obj as ActionGroup;
                group.WriteXml(w);
            }
        }

        w.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

I've got the above code in my ActionGroup class.  An ActionGroup contains actions and actiongroups.  When I try to serialize it, any group beyond the first level throws an exception as soon as it hits the first line of the method.

"Token StartAttribute in state Content would result in an invalid XML document."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably happens if you have an object of the `IAction` type and an object of the `ActionGroup` in `Actions` (in this order). `XmlSerializer` will close the open "Actions" start element and will serialize the `IAction` object so you will end up with something like this:

```
<Actions><IAction />
```

Now you see an `ActionGroup` and call the `WriteXml` which first wants to write attributes but if it did just that it would result in

```
<Actions><IAction />Name="actionName" Type="actionType"
```

Given that you request to write `Name` and `Type` as attributes it makes an invalid Xml because you can write attributes only on an element and not in the content hence the exception.

Comment: That looks to be exactly what is happening.  How do I get around it?  I would have thought it wouldn't close the open tag until the WriteEndElement call.

Comment: If a tag is open and you start creating a new element it closes the open tag otherwise it would be an invalid element (e.g. `<Element1<Element2`). You need to refactor your code - I don't have enough context but it struck me that the methods starts from writing attributes instead of an element.

Comment: So WriteStartElement("Actions");only creates "<Actions"?

I was under the impression that it would create "<Actions>" and then I could write stuff in between and then later a WriteEndElement call would write "</Actions>".  Is that not correct?

Comment: I believe it just creates `<Actions` and then closes it or not depending on what you do next. If it created `<Actions>` how would you append attributes? They require a non-closed tag. This also help ensure that the Xml you are writing is valid (as you have experienced it)